# how to add captured image dynamically into a Horizontal scroll view

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new to android programming,can anyone tell me how to add captured image dynamically into a horizontal scroll view. A sample code is much more helpful.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far for it?

Comment: Just Take Picture From Camera And Use ArrayList to Store Image Path Ans Use HorizontalListview with Coustem Adapter when pic Image Add image Path in arrayList ans Create or Updated Yore Adapter i also DO this In My app

Comment: your code will work fine when grid view is used but i need to insert those pictures inside HorizontalScrollView->LinearLayout,Images should be displayed inside LinearLayout where orientation is set to Horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

Add in xml

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/RelativeGridLayout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<GridView
android:id="@+id/gridviewimg"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:numColumns="2"
android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
android:smoothScrollbar="true"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="50dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/RelativeGridLayout"
>

<Button
android:id="@+id/capture_btn1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:text="Camera" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Add in MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button captureBtn = null;
    final int CAMERA_CAPTURE = 1;
    private Uri picUri;
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    private GridView grid;
    private  List<String> listOfImagesPath;

    public static final String GridViewDemo_ImagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/GridViewDemo/";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        captureBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.capture_btn1);
        grid = ( GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridviewimg);

        listOfImagesPath = null;
        listOfImagesPath = RetriveCapturedImagePath();
        if(listOfImagesPath!=null){
        grid.setAdapter(new ImageListAdapter(this,listOfImagesPath));
        captureBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    //use standard intent to capture an image
                    Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    //we will handle the returned data in onActivityResult
                    startActivityForResult(captureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
                    } catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
                    //display an error message
                    String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support capturing images!";

                    }
            }
        });

        }
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //user is returning from capturing an image using the camera
        if(requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE){
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
        String imgcurTime = dateFormat.format(new Date());
        File imageDirectory = new File(GridViewDemo_ImagePath);
        imageDirectory.mkdirs();
        String _path = GridViewDemo_ImagePath + imgcurTime+".jpg";
        try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(_path);
        thePic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        listOfImagesPath = null;
        listOfImagesPath = RetriveCapturedImagePath();
        if(listOfImagesPath!=null){
        grid.setAdapter(new ImageListAdapter(this,listOfImagesPath));
        }
        }
        }
        }

        private List<String> RetriveCapturedImagePath() {
        List<String> tFileList = new ArrayList<String>();
        File f = new File(GridViewDemo_ImagePath);
        if (f.exists()) {
        File[] files=f.listFiles();
        Arrays.sort(files);

        for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++){
        File file = files[i];
        if(file.isDirectory())
        continue;
        tFileList.add(file.getPath());
        }
        }
        return tFileList;
        }

        public class ImageListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
        {
        private Context context;
        private List<String> imgPic;
        public ImageListAdapter(Context c, List<String> thePic)
        {
        context = c;
        imgPic = thePic;
        }
        public int getCount() {
        if(imgPic != null)
        return imgPic.size();
        else
        return 0;
        }

        //---returns the ID of an item---
        public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
        }

        //---returns an ImageView view---
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
        ImageView imageView;
        BitmapFactory.Options bfOptions=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bfOptions.inDither=false;                     //Disable Dithering mode
        bfOptions.inPurgeable=true;                   //Tell to gc that whether it needs free memory, the Bitmap can be cleared
        bfOptions.inInputShareable=true;              //Which kind of reference will be used to recover the Bitmap data after being clear, when it will be used in the future
        bfOptions.inTempStorage=new byte[32 * 1024];
        if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        FileInputStream fs = null;
        Bitmap bm;
        try {
        fs = new FileInputStream(new File(imgPic.get(position).toString()));

        if(fs!=null) {
        bm=BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fs.getFD(), null, bfOptions);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
        imageView.setId(position);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 160));
        }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
        if(fs!=null) {
        try {
        fs.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
        }
        return imageView;
        }
        }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Add in Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: there is nothing horizential scroll view gridview is scroll vertical

Comment: Thank you,your code will work fine when grid view is used but i need to insert those captured pictures inside HorizontalScrollView->LinearLayout,Images should be displayed inside LinearLayout where orientation is set to Horizontal and can we insert or display (voice clip,Images and Scribble )files with a tiles in the same linear Layout???

Comment: ok, u can mail me , so i can send u complete source code, jeetendra.gupta21@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your layout where you want to display horizontal scrollview

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/ll" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/View_photo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Add Image xml as follows

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dip"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/resultimage"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image_form">
</ImageView>
```

Add this to your activity

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    LinearLayoutInHorizontalscrollview.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.imagexml, null),lp);
    Images = (Linearlayout) view.getChildAt(i);
    Images.setId(id);//for easy accessibitility
    ImageView =(ImageView)Images.findViewById(R.id.resultimage);
```

set your image to this imageView in whichever way you intend.Better load Images in AsyncTask.